# The OAuth response flow failed

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, deep-linking, react-native-linking, react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

I'm using [aws amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/hub/q/platform/js/) along with [react-native-inappbrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser). I enabled Google SSO authentication and it is working fine, but when I added GitHub auth it doesn't work as expected.
I added a listener using `Hub.listen('auth', async (data) => {...}` and the `urlOpener` in my `awsConfig` looks like this:

```
onst urlOpener = async (url, redirectUrl, settings) => {
  try {
    if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
      const { type, url: newUrl } = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(
        url,
        redirectUrl,
        { ...inAppBrowserSettings, ...settings },
      );
      if (type === 'success') {
        Linking.openURL(newUrl);
      }
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(url);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert(error.message);
  }
};
```

The `Hub.listener` looks like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen('auth', async (data) => {
      const { payload } = data;
      const user = payload.data;
      switch (payload.event) {
        case AuthEnum.SIGN_IN:
          handleSignIn(user);
          break;
        case AuthEnum.SIGN_OUT:
          handleSignOut();
          break;
        case AuthEnum.SIGN_IN_FAILURE:
          handleSignInFailure();
          break;
      }

    });
   return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

When I try to authenticate using GitHub, the GitHub API returns the correct token but the aws `Hub` catches a `SIGN_IN_FAILURE` and the `data` looks like this:

```
{
  "channel": "auth",
  "payload": {
    "event": "signIn_failure",
    "data": {},
    "message": "The OAuth response flow failed"
  },
  "source": "Auth",
  "patternInfo": []
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. A solution could be to remove the listener in case of GitHub auth, but I'm not sure how to do that since the `InAppBrowser.openAuth()` is used for both the Google SSO and GitHub auth.

Make sure to let me know if the info I provided isn't enough. Any suggestions/help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AWS Amplify support github oauth. I believe the supported ones are: Google, Apple, Facebook & Amazon

[Supported social logins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET02q.png)